# How to have a pair whose second element is a list?

Tags: list, scheme

I'd like to have a pair whose second element *may* be either a symbol or a list. For example, `'(x . y)` and `'(x . (a b c d))` are both valid pairs in my context. If the second element is just a symbol, I can get the pair with `cons`, but what if it is a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you still use `cons` The scheme printer is just better at printing those sort of pairs vs other ones. That's the only reason they look different.

```
> (define x '(1 2 3))
> (car (cons 0 x))
  0
> (cdr (cons 0 x))
  (1 2 3)
```

Scheme lists are really just defined recursively by this formula

1. A list is a pair of datum and a list
2. `'()` is a list. (Really that's totally arbitrary and could be anything, `'()` is just a very strong tradition)

[image: Here's a pretty picture of it.]

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `cons` to do it.

```
(cons 'x '(a b c d))   ; => (x a b c d)
```